# I earned -1 reputation, how do I see this?

Tags: support

So I noticed the little green badge with the number 9 in it in my AD toolbar so I clicked on it to get the details and this comes up

[image: Reputation]

I understand what the +10 means (and from where) but was curious about the "-1" so I clicked on it and it took me to my profile page, with no indication of what the -1 was for.

Hey we all make mistakes and I am curious why I got the -1 and on what comment, answer or something else.

I am not sure how to find it, nor can I seem to find *how* to find it either. Wrong search terms no doubt. Can someone clue me in, please?

Answer (score 3):

The likely explanation for the -1 is that you downvoted an answer, which decrements your own reputation by 1 as well as the answer’s author by 2.

You should be able to see the post that the -1 is attributed to in the reputation tab of your profile: https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=reputation

Comment: Well, problem is, there is no indication of any downvotes on https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/33273/steve-chambers?tab=reputation&sort=post

Comment: @nohillside Only the user who cast the vote can see the -1 otherwise that would leak attribution to votes.

Comment: Oh. Well, be patient with a newbie like me :)

Comment: Well, cool, I learned something new, thx!